# Complicated Transposed Table With Powershell or Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to manipulate the layout of a file-share report. Basically what the layout looks like now is this:

```
Path,Username/Group
path1,user1
path2,user1
path3,user1
path1,user2
path3,group1
path2,group2
```

It's showing folder paths and what users have access to them.
I'd like to change this to the following layout:

```
user1,user2,group1,group2
path1,path1,path3,path2
path2
path3
```

Whether it be importing the data into excel and manipulating it in excel or using powershell script to manipulate the data, I'm not quite sure what to do to get it the way I want.

I've tried importing this text file into excel and trying to transpose but I can't figure out how to show a list of file paths for each user. I've messed around in Access with it as well, but I'm not experienced enough in access to get it to display properly. I tried a few things in powershell but it amounted to a bunch of text documents named after the users with a list of file paths in each document. Not quite as neat as I'd like it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell could do it. Assuming the data is what you show in the question it looks like a CSV file. You could do:

```
$DataIn = Import-CSV $file
$HTOut = @{}
$File | Group 'Username/Group' | ForEach{$HTOut.add($_.Name,$_.Group.Path)}
New-Object PSObject -Prop $HTOut | Export-CSV $file
```

I thought about it, and this doesn't do exactly what I had said, it would make one object with a property for each user/group, and that property's value would be all of the paths for that person/group. What you really want is X objects that iterate through all of those paths. For that the first 3 lines stay the same, except that we capture the number of paths for the user/group with the most paths. Then we make that many objects iterating through paths for each user.

```
$DataIn = Import-CSV $file
$HTOut = @{}
$MaxPaths = $DataIn | Group 'Username/Group' | ForEach{$HTOut.add($_.Name,$_.Group.Path);$_} |% Count |Sort -Descend |Select -first 1
$Results = For($i=0;$i -le $MaxPaths;$i++){
    $Record = New-Object PSObject
    $HTOut.Keys|ForEach{Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $(([array]$HTOut["$_"])[$i])}
    $Record
}
```

Comment: I was gonna say, the script you posted gave me a pretty weird looking csv. lol. I'll try your second solution as soon as I can and report back. thank you for the help.

Comment: When I opened the new CSV after running the second script, I have a blank worksheet.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test my code, I just wrote it off the top of my head. I fixed it, tested it, and it should be good to go now.

Comment: The actual file has "Account" instead of Username/Group. I thought I could just change the $MaxPaths = $DataIn | Group 'Username/Group' portion of the script to $MaxPaths = $DataIn | Group 'Account' but this seems to give me an error. I'll post the error in the next comment.

Comment: Add-Member : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NotePropertyName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not 
null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:8 char:75
+     $HTOut.Keys|ForEach{Add-Member -InputObject $Record -NotePropertyName $_ -No ...
+                                                                           ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand

Comment: Make sure that everything has a value in the Account column then, because that implies that is not the case.

Comment: That's exactly what the issue was. I removed the blank Account Name entries and it worked like a charm. Thank you!